# What is this icon about and how common it is among non designers/developers?

Tags: icon, designers, symbols

I was looking for an icon called RSS for using it as Media icon. That's a different thing and that's not point of this question.

[image]
[image]

The thing is, now I'm wondering what the following icon (1st image) is actually about. When I search on for RSS icon on TheNounProject, I found this icon.

But I see similar icons for keywords like news, feed, press also.

So I became curious (and careful too so I might not end up for using something that doesn't represent what I would need for my projects) and I thought it might be possible it has many meanings and can be used for more than one thing.

And so to know more, I read about RSS on Wikipedia (couldn't understand much) it gave me hint that it is some kind of file that contains news but understood by computer only. That made me clear that yes, it is icon for RSS at least. But that also made me doubtful that if this icon is just like other icons on web/mobile apps or general audience who don't work in IT or design field wouldn't understand it.

Later, I continued *research* and found out that same icon also shows up when you search for news/feed/press.

I also observed this now (see, the icon is used in notification. It might help understand question better and answer better):
[image]

Query 1: So I'm wondering if it has **multiple meanings**?

Query 2: Is it used for general audience (just like battery, camera, network signals, Wi-Fi, alarm, notification, search, home, etc. icons which non designers/non tech guys can also understand)? **If yes, what does it symbolize or for what purpose?**

Query 3: Is it used for tech/developers purpose (only)? **If yes, what does it symbolize or for what purpose?**

Comment: I don't *really* know what's being asked here.. there are a bunch of random questions which all *seem* rather rhetorical. There's no "focus" in the question. An RSS icon is specific and typically *means* an RSS feed. Using it for general "news" would be like using a USB icon for "connectivity" -- yes it's related, but the icon is very specific and typically means only one thing. Just because you may be unfamiliar with an RSS feed, I assure you there are thousands, if not millions, who aren't. Wifi and RSS icons are *not* the same. Wifi has curves bottom up, while RSS is from a corner out.

Comment: @Scott made it better :)

Comment: RSS is a nifty way for a user to fetch their own newsfeeds without needing to go trough the interface of a news site. This way youvcan always have a news agregate that is tailored to your needs. News organisations have mostly deorecated RSS feeds and replaced it with things like facebook.

Comment: @joojaa so does that mean RSS feed isn't for *normal people*? And its for people who have to deal with news websites?

Let me make it more clear. Notification icon is for everyone. Be it a teacher, farmer, artist, you or me whatever. Is RSS is mainly for news website users who manage them?

Comment: RSS is for *anyone* who knows how to use it, Vikas.

Comment: @Vikas no it does not mean that. RSS is just as normal as any webpage. You can not draw the conclusion that if you dont know something nobody does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RSS icon is specific and typically means an RSS feed.

Using the RSS icon for general "news" would be like using a USB icon for "connectivity" when you are actually referring to internet connectivity -- yes it's related, but the icon is very specific and typically means only one thing. The USB icon *means* USB connectivity, not simply general connectivity.

Just because you may be unfamiliar with an RSS feed, I assure you there are thousands, if not millions, who aren't. **If you aren't using an RSS feed, then using the RSS icon would be inappropriate.**

Wifi and RSS icons are not the same. Wifi has curves bottom up, while RSS is from a corner out.

The RSS icon specifically relates to an XML new fees and RSS readers. Users see it, and expect to find an RSS feed. It is *not* only a "development" thing.